# Is there any function to get the last entry in groupby in query builder or eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have query which is group by the jobseeker_id to get the unique one,because there are some a few same jobseeker_id but difference value like status and call_reason columns.And I want to get the latest entry record base on the id or the created_at date.I can only get the number or date by using MAX function.But for the other alphabet words, i coundn't use MAX anymore because they just giving me the first item of the words ,dun give me the max(id)or max(created_at)result row of the status and call_reason.Here is my query ...

```
             $jobseekers =DB::table('calllogs')
              -  ->select('status','call_reason','id','jobseeker_id',DB::raw("MAX(id),MAX(created_at)"))
              ->groupBy('jobseeker_id')
              ->get();

                var_dump($jobseekers);
```

In normal mysql,it's so simple you can go check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby_orderby.)
I can just use the max(id) or max(created_at) infront of the select.

Any one have an idea?

Comment: You can execute the raw query in laravel if you have working sql query

Comment: Order by what you need and limit 1